Allauth SocialConnectView django rest framework
Please help. The access token retrieved from Facebook is not stored in the socialaccount_token table after a successful social login. This prevents my application from using the token later for data retrieval. this is my code
from dj_rest_auth.registration.views import SocialConnectView
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook.views import FacebookOAuth2Adapter
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.oauth2.client import OAuth2Client

class FacebookConnect(SocialConnectView):
    adapter_class = FacebookOAuth2Adapter
    client_class = OAuth2Client

the data are stored in the socialaccount_socialaccount table by default, but nothing is stored in the socialaccount_socialtoken.
